# Removing special characters from a string with RegEx

Tags: c#, regex, special-characters

Am reading a text file that contains words, numbers and special characters, I want to remove certain special characters like: `[](),'`

I have this code but it is not working !

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader ("C://Users//HP//Documents//result2.txt")) {
            string line = reader.ReadToEnd ();

            Regex rgx = new Regex ("[^[]()',]");
            string res = rgx.Replace (line, "");
            Message1.text = res;

        }
```

what am I missing, thanks

Comment: Almost all of these characters are special characters in Regex. They must be properly escaped.

Comment: What should I do ?

Comment: just use `.Replace()`

Comment: .Replace() is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the characters in your Regex, specifically `[ ] ( ) ^`, hold [special meaning in Regex](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcharacters.html) and in order to use them literally they must be escaped.

Use the following properly escaped Regex:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex (@"[\^\[\]\(\)',]");
```

Note that it is necessary to use the `@` verbatim string, because we don't want to escape these characters *from the string*, only from the Regex.

Alternatively, double escape the backslashes:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex ("[\\^\\[\\]\\(\\)',]");
```

But that's less readable in this case.

Comment: There is no need escaping these chars. [`"[][()'^,]"` will work](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5d%5b%28%29%27%5e%2c%5d&i=%5b%5d%5b%28%29%27%5e%2c%5d&r=x).

Answer (score 1):

You could skip Regex and just maintain a list of characters you want to remove and then replace the old fashioned way:

```
string[] specialCharsToRemove = new [] { "[", "]", "(", ")", "'", "," };

using (var reader = new StreamReader ("C://Users//HP//Documents//result2.txt")) 
{
    string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
    foreach(string s in specialCharsToRemove)
    {
        line = line.Replace(s, string.Empty);
    } 
    Message1.text = res;            
}
```

Ideally this would be in its own method, something like this:

```
private static string RemoveCharacters(string input, string[] specialCharactersToRemove)
{
    foreach(string s in specialCharactersToRemove)
    {
        input = input.Replace(s, string.Empty);
    }
    return input;
}
```

I made a fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JCSsri)

Answer (score 0):

Replace them one at a time with String.Replace:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader ("C://Users//HP//Documents//result2.txt")) 
{
        string line = reader.ReadToEnd ();

        string res = line.Replace(line, "[", "");
        res  = res.Replace(line, "]", "");
        res  = res.Replace(line, "(", "");
        res  = res.Replace(line, ")", "");
        res  = res.Replace(line, "'", "");
        res  = res.Replace(line, ",", "");
        Message1.text = res;

    }
```

Comment: just fixed a typo

Comment: A `foreach` would be nicer and easier to modify.

Comment: i considered that

Answer (score 0):

I agree with avoiding regex for this, but I would not use string.Replace multiple times, either.

Consider implementing a Replace or Remove method that accepts an array of characters to replace, and scan the input string only once. For example:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char ch in input)
{
    if (!chars.Contains(ch))
    {
        builder.Append(ch):
    }
}

return builder.ToString();
```